# Istio Virtual Service gives 404 if passed @RequestParam in API end points routing

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks, istio

I want to route through Istio virtual Service to my microservice. When I use `@RequestParam` based input in prefix or even in exact it throws `404` for `/api/cities/{city_id}/tours` but the rest works fine.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: nsapp
spec:
  gateways:
    - app-gateway
  hosts:
    - app.*.*.*
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/cities/{city_id}/tours"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/countries/{country_id}/cities"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/countries"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: appservice
        port:
          number: 9090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment

```yaml
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/cities/{city_id}/tours"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/countries/{country_id}/cities"
```

will be taken literally. The `{city_id}` and  `{country_id}` will not be replaced with your custom ID. At this point, istio will look for a prefix that reads literally `/api/cities/{city_id}/tours` or `/api/countries/{country_id}/cities`, which doesn't exist (you get error 404). If you want to match the expression to your custom ID you have to use a regular expression. Look at [this doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#StringMatch). There you will find information about the capabilities of the StringMatch: `exact`, `prefix` or `regex`. You can find the syntax of the regular expressions used in istio [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Summary:
You should change `prefix` to `regex` and then create your own regular expression to match your custom ID. Example:

```yaml
    - uri:
        regex: "/api/cities/[a-zA-Z]+/tours"
    - uri:
        regex: "/api/countries/[a-zA-Z]+/cities"
```

In my example, there are only letters (upper or lower case) in the ID. Here you have to create your own regular expression based on [this documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Yes, This regex approach helps to resolve issue, although I tried bit and finally able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix matching matches literal strings.

`/api/countries` also matches what you intend to match with  `/api/countries/{country_id}/cities`

`/api/cities/{city_id}/tours` however, does not work.

For more complex matching, you can use an exact and regex, as described in the [`VirtualService`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest) documentation.

Maybe something like this (untested):

```
exact: "/api/countries"
regex: "/api/countries/[^/]*/cities"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:-**

I tried as below and found out it to be working, adding solution which I tested and is working. Basically, steps performed are:-

removed prefix: "/api/countries/{country_id}/cities" as /api/countries/ is common String to 2 APIs, and eventually, It is able to route to both the APIs on original appservice host respectively and same with /api/cities.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: nsapp
spec:
  gateways:
    - app-gateway
  hosts:
    - app.*.*.*
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/cities"
    - uri:
        prefix: "/api/countries"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: appservice
        port:
          number: 9090
```